# Problem with savin data!

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a UitableView and its a checklist. I want to be able to save data when the user leaves the view. Then when the view is opened back up i want there to be the saved data. When i say saved data i mean that the table view is able to add and delete cells also i want to be able to save the checkmarks. Could somebody please provide me with a way or an idea on how to do this?

i know i can save data with:

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

and then save the data to defaults, but i need know how on saving the table view's cells that are add and or deleted! also i would like to know how to save the checkmarks!

Thank you, 
Kurt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using either Core Data, or NSCoding.  NSCoding allows you to encode an object as NSData, and reload a replica of that object from NSData.

For instance, saving and loading an array of strings through NSCoding would be something like this:

```
NSArray * array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"This", @"Is", @"A", @"Test"];
NSData * encoded = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
// save the encoded data to a file...
// load the encoded data from a file...
NSArray * decodedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encoded];
```

Of course, you will need to implement some NSCoding stuff yourself if you plan on using classes more complicated than NSDictionary, NSArray, NSString, etc.

Documentation for NSKeyedArchiver can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  You can also find documentation for the NSCoding protocol [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like core data would be good here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html